# Iterate awk function for every unique field in column

Tags: awk

I have write an awk script to analyse my table data - I am calculating p-value and log2 odds ratio.
This is an example of data table I have.

```
Label      Value1     Value2      

Label1       9          6
Label1       7          6 
Label1       1          6
Label2       5          7
Label2       3          7
Label2       8          7
```

For every label (`Label1/2`) I count how many times `value1 > value2` and divide this number by total times `Label` was observed - I am getting p-value.
Additionally to this, I compare their log2 ratio.
This is my awk script.

```
 awk '{a[$1]=$1}; ($2>=$3) {c++}; {sum+=$2} END 
      {print c/NR,log($3/(sum/NR))/log(2),a[$1]}'
```

And this is result I get

```
0.666667 0.0824622 Label1
```

Column1 is p-value; Column 2 is odds ratio; Column 3 is Label.

Problem is that I don't know how to apply this calculation for both `Labels` - I am getting result only for the first one.

**My question is - how to iterate such awk function for every unique field in column 1 (`Label1/2`)**

Comment: You need to add the expect output to your question. It's not clear exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I assume two lines before first line of data, so I compare `NR` with 3. The program saves previous label name (`$1`) and only when it changes (`$1 != label`) it does the calculations and print. Other condition (`NR >= 3`) only saves data while processing same label.

```
awk '
    NR == 3 { label = $1 }
    NR >=3 && $1 != label { 
        printf "%.6f %.6f %s\n", c/l, log( v / (sum/l) ) / log(2), label
        c = l = sum = 0
        label = $1
    }
    NR >= 3 {
        if ( $2 >= $3 ) { c++ }
        l++
        sum += $2
        v = $3
    }
    END {
        printf "%.6f %.6f %s\n", c/l, log( v / (sum/l) ) / log(2), label
    }
' infile
```

It yields:

```
0.666667 0.082462 Label1
0.333333 0.392317 Label2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way with `awk` (using arrays):

```
awk '
NR>1 && $2>$3 {
    times[$1]++
} 
{
    total[$1]+=$2;
    col3[$1]=$3;
    seen[$1]++
}
END {
    for(label in times) {
        print times[label]/seen[label],log(col3[label]/(total[label]/seen[label]))/log(2),label
    }
}' inputFile
```

#### Output:

```
0.666667 0.0824622 Label1
0.333333 0.392317 Label2
```